# initial DNS zone transfer too slow, too slow to update, any configuration to speed it up?

Tags: dns, vmware

I have configured a master/Slave zone, the initial zone transfer is too slow and no changes have happened over the course of 10 mins, the only update I have seen so far is 2 updates, this is in a test VMs and not production, there is hardly any data in it. Could it be a misconfiguration, I have changed TTL, refresh, retry to 100, yet nothing happens, tried bumping up the serial as well to get an update, no change. The first time I got it working it was quicker, now I repeated the same setup with a new IP and it's too slow. I have [read this](https://serverfault.com/questions/531072/bind-slave-slow-to-update-zones) and have added it in my zone files as well, still it's dead slow.

Forward Zone

```
$TTL 3H
$ORIGIN L00144445.local.

@       IN SOA ns1.L00144445.local. admin.L00144445.local. (
                                        0       ; serial
                                        1D      ; refresh
                                        1H      ; retry
                                        1W      ; expire
                                        3H )    ; minimum
        IN NS ns1.L00144445.local.

        IN NS ns2.L00144445.local.

ns1     IN A 192.168.102.191

ns2     IN A 192.168.102.192
```

Reverse Zone

```
$TTL 3H
$ORIGIN 102.168.192.IN-ADDR.ARPA.

@       IN SOA ns1.L00144445.local. admin.L00144445.local. (
                                        0              ; serial
                                        1D      ; refresh
                                        1H      ; retry
                                        1W      ; expire
                                        3H )    ; minimum
        IN NS ns1.L00144445.local.

        IN NS ns2.L00144445.local.

191     IN PTR ns1.L00144445.local.

192     IN PTR ns2.L00144445.local.
```

Anything else I should do to speed up the initial update ?

Comment: It took about 30 minutes to complete the zone update, if someone could explain what happens in the background that takes this much time, that would be great..

Comment: It would help to say which dns software you are using. After that you should say what commands you run after you update the master to encourage the slave to get the updated data.

Comment: Sorry didnt realize that, I'm using the BIND  v9, the command to update is named -u named -g -p 53 to get the Slave to update..

Comment: `named -u named -g -p 53` runs the named command in the foreground. My understanding is these days you want to run `rndc` when you change the data, but I haven't used `bind` in decades.

Comment: I tried rndc reload, didn't change anything, I believe it has not much effect in BIND v9..

Comment: Did you change the serial number before you did the reload?

Comment: Are you blocking tcp 53?

Comment: I did not try to change the serial before an rndc reload, and no tcp 53 is not blocked, its explicitly added to firewalld, I will try and change the serial and run and rndc reload and see..

Comment: So I changed the serial and performed rndc reload, what happens is that soon as I reload rndc the slave starts the update but never finishes it, it shows transfer complete for both zones but hasn't shown zone is up to date, it still on going..

Comment: Today morning, I just changed the serial from 0 to 1 and all of a sudden the Slave showed zone up to date, but nothing happened on the Master side, is it suppose to be like that or will both ends show a zone up to date notification ?

Comment: Any time you make changes to your zone file you must update the serial.  Basically, when a primary starts up it sends notices to secondaries, with the serial.  If the serial is newer, the secondaries accept and update.  When a secondary (re)starts, it queries its primary for current serial, and updates if the primary serial is newer (higher value).  FWIW I've not played with ipv6 but any time I've made changes, updated serial, and restarted the service the notifications and needed transfers have happened instantly, bind9 on debian and/or ubuntu

Comment: I understand that part, however, there is a new problem, the zone up to date does not show in the terminal when performing the zone transfer, it only shows this zone upda to date in /var/log/message file, how can I get it to show on the terminal display during zone transfer..

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem to be ipv6 configuration which kept on attempting to update the zones as well, this was found in **/var/log/messages** log file, and since it was pre-configured in its default setting, it would keep on attempting to update zone right after ipv4 is updated thus no response was even received.

Removed all references of ipv6 from **/etc/named.conf**, and added the following options to **/etc/sysonfig/named** file.

**RESOLVCONF=yes**

**OPTIONS=-4**

Now it updates instantly.

Comment: Good job. Though supposedly BIND has algorithms to prevent this...